# Scheme game board cat

Tags: list, matrix, scheme, cat

I'm trying to do a cat suit but I'm still new in Scheme.

Implement the recursive predicate winner? receive an array of symbols 
represent a game board cat (ordered by line) and a mark of 
player, and determine whether the player has won the game. Remember that winning is 
must be 3 brands online, horizontally, vertically or diagonally.

```
(winner? ‘((X X v)(v O O)(X v O)) ‘O) => #f
(winner? ‘((X v X)(O O O)(X v O)) ‘O) => #t
(winner? ‘((X X O)(v O O)(X v O)) ‘O) => #t 
(winner? ‘((X X O)(v O O)(O v X)) ‘O) => #t
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not using the quote char `'` but one of the smart quotes. It will not work so you should change it to `'`.

So you explain yourself there are 3 ways you can win:

```scm
(define (winner? board sym)
  (or (winner-horizontal? board sym)
      (winner-vertical? board sym)
      (winner-diagonal? board sym)))
```

If you use `unzip`, defined as follows:

```scm
(define (unzip lst)
  (apply map list lst))
```

You can turn a board:

```scm
(unzip ‘((X X O)(v O O)(X v O))) ; ==> ((X v X) (X O v) (O O O))
```

That makes `winner-vertical` redundant since you can use `winner-horizontal` on a `unzipped` board:

```scm
(define (winner? board sym)
  (or (winner-horizontal? board sym)
      (winner-horizontal? (unzip board) sym)
      (winner-diagonal? board sym)))
```

There you go. You now have two smaller problems to solve. Hope it helps you on your way. To get more specific help you need to post some code on your own (show effort).